# Redirect from an asp.net mvc application to a .aspx file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, button, razor, webforms

I have a button in an **asp.net MVC 5** web application and I'm trying to redirect the user to an **.aspx** file. 
So that when the user clicks on a button from asp.net MVC (the code of that button is in HTML), he will be redirected to a web form (.apsx).
I tried this code but it doesn't work.

```
<button id="Login" runat="server" OnClientClick="window.open('Login.aspx', 'Login');">Login </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to call .aspx page in your Action method.

```
public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return Redirect("~/Login.aspx");
    }
```

Comment: I'm only starting with asp.net, can you please tell me where to add this code? I want to add it to a button.

Comment: Why does it have to be on the server? This could easily be accomplished on the client.

Comment: You can use Postbackurl    <button id="Login" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/Login.aspx" >Login </button>

Comment: No, you can't. Razor doesn't have the concept a button that can runat the server. It's great that you're trying to help, but you need to know about how exactly these frameworks function before trying to assist others with it.

Comment: Thank you both for your feedback, I tried that and it didn't work. I want to redirect the button only to another .aspx page. How is this possible? I tried looking on different forums but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/Login.aspx")">
  <button type="button">Login</button>
</a>
```

You can embed a button in a hyperlink, so that it appears like a button but works like a link. The trick is getting the URL set correctly. In mixed Web Forms/MVC projects I use the `Url.Content` helper because it respects the virtual root. You might do well to create a route class however.

```
public class WebFormsRoutes
{
    public const string LoginPage = "~/Login.aspx";
}
```

With the appropriate namespaces imported, you can then do:

```
<a href="@Url.Content(WebFormsRoutes.LoginPage)">
  <button type="button">Login</button>
</a>
```

You might also consider looking at the [routing documentation](https://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/routing). You can register your own Web Forms routes for friendlier URL's

Answer (score -1):

Your code does not look like a Razor View Code. 
You can do it multiple ways

1.`<button onclick="window.open('Login.aspx')">Login</button>`
 2. Using Razor

```
<button onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Login","Login")'">Login</button>
```

Thanks
Partha

Comment: You can't use `Url.Action` to generate a URL for a Web Forms page. You can use `Url.Content` however.